# Is there a list of values I can use for objectClass and objectCategory?

Tags: c#-4.0, active-directory, ldap

I'm new to LDAP queries so I have been reading up on it to use in my application since I want to use filters to get certain results against Active Directory. I'm still a little confused and just want some clarification on somethings.

It seems like for **objectClass** theres User, Contact and inetOrgPerson 
For example:

```
(&(objectClass=user))
```

For **objectCategory** Person, Computer, and Group.

Is there more values to objectClass and objectCategory besides the ones I listed?

Also is this a good list of most if not all the attributes and classes for objectClass and objectCategory?

http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ape/#objectclasses

Answer (score 2):

The correct and authoritative source for LDAP attribute and objectClasses is [IETF](http://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/search/?name=lightweight%20directory%20access%20protocol&rfcs=on&activeDrafts=on&search_submit=), not zytrax. There are number of RFCs describing (more or less) standardized object classes and attributes. Each vendor may have objectClasses and attributes specific to their implementation, consult the vendor documentation for this information, although strictly speaking, applications should not be coded with knowledge of an implementation.

Comment: Yea I was just looking for an easy quick reference for object classes and category. Is that a good site for that?

Comment: The standards documentation plus the vendor documentation are the only documentation you should consult. Anything else, however "easy" and "quick", would not be definitive. To understand more about LDAP schema design, the best reference thus far is still the old "Understanding and Deploying LDAP Directory Services", ISBN 978-1578700707

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll definitely take a look at it. Is there a reason why these books are so old? LDAP just don't change that much?

Answer (score 0):

You should give a look to the Active Directory Schema.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675085%28v=vs.85%29.aspx